# AngularJS: pass variable from backend while loading a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails

This is my first ever trial with Angular JS and am stuck at a very basic step. I have an AngularJS front end and Grails backend. Below are the code snippets I have followed by my question.

1. URL Mapping entry:

as

```
"/graph"(controller: 'Graph')
```

2. This is my Grails controller/action which renders the GSP:

as

```
class GraphController {
    def index() {
        render(view: "../graph", model: [employeeId: "197040"])
    }
}
```

3. This is the AngularJS file, which is saved as graph.gsp:

[image]

When I give the URL: hostname:port/graph I am able to see the body displayed as "Hi ! Welcome". But, I couldn't figure out a ( simple ) way to read that employeeId and display it as "Hi ! Welcome 197040" ( i.e being able to read that variable employeeId sent from backend)

`<div><h3>Hi ! Welcome {{employeeId}}</h3></div>` didn't work as expected.

I am sorry if this is too basic a question, but I just couldn't see the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other thing here is, this is gsp afterall.. and your grails variables will work as per normal like how you defined the layout..

```
<div><h3>Hi ! Welcome ${employeeId}</h3></div>
```

Which will be grails pushing that info back....

The alternative is something like this: as shown per service on this demo site..
https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testingarrested/blob/master/grails-app/assets/javascripts/testingarrested/arrestedServices.js

Maybe you wish to try out arrestedplugin for yourself as a demo and then take the for example above service and change it for your own usage..

Comment: I almost wanted to 'accept' the answer you provided. Don't know why this simple thing didn't occur to me. I proceeded according your suggestion and made some heads up. But while ${employeeId} is giving tha value in some places, in another place while passing ${employeeId} as a parameter to a JS function it was giving undefined

Comment: angular is layered so if you have nested controllers being called one heigher holding on to a value or even passing such values to $rootScope would help ease on this sort of issue... also if employeeID was a session u could do a gsp call on page anytime for it....  <g:set var="lang" value="${session.   https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testingarrested/blob/master/grails-app/assets/javascripts/custom-testingarrested/dashboardCtrl.js -- you could have a higher controller defined through out all your angular pages that initially does some get and stores rootScope.username as the value it got.....

Comment: Your not supposed to go wild on it. You can just inject rootscope into any controller and get set values.... but as mentioned its global where as scope is local to xontroller. But forgot about james method so gonna up him myself. .

Comment: If you have the time create new app install the arrested plugin. You will see rootScope calls in higher layers I.e. usercontrl and navbar etc... you can also get ideas on how to run services that query grails app and return result to angular.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<div ng-init="employeeId=${employeeId}"><h3>Hi ! Welcome {{employeeId}}</h3></div>
```

This will assign the value of the employeeId within the context of the GSP to a variable available within the context of Angular. To understand what I mean, take a look at the generated HTML source in your browser.

By doing this, the employeeId variable will be assigned within the scope of your Angular controller also.

There is a good tutorial on using Angular with Grails here http://claymccoy.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/grails-with-angularjs-and-coffeescript.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks you James. That's precisely what I did in my code as well ( going by @vahid's answer above ). I am going to mark your answer as 'useful' as I already accepted the earlier answer. And thanks a ton for that tutorial link. I wish I could 'Up' your answer more :)

Answer (score 2):

Your Angular app runs on the user's browser and has no access to your backend environment. Therefore simply setting employeeId as a backend environment variable does not allow Angular to access it.

I can recommend two solutions to this problem:

1) In the index view (/graph), render employeeId as a JavaScript global in a script tag. In Angular, register the global employeeId as an Angular value. Then you can inject the employeeId value into your Angular controller and render it in the Angular view.

2) Retrieve the employeeId asynchronously via Ajax before your Angular app bootstraps, and register it as an Angular value. Then you can inject it to your controller. I recently wrote a blog post about how this can be done: http://biodegreeprogrammer.blogspot.ca/2014/07/pre-loading-data-asynchronously-in.html

Comment: Thank you for the options. As of now I am having some progress by using ${employeeId} in the angularjs ( saved as gsp ) file. But it is not clean yet. Could you please give me sample code snippets for both the options you suggested? Appreciate your help in advance.